Quasar, Material icons, font-variation-settings not worked
Im using quasar framework and Material Icons as iconset (Material Icons Outlined)
Im trying change weight of icons
Docs says
<style>
.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings:
  'FILL' 0,
  'wght' 100,
  'GRAD' 0,
  'opsz' 24
}
</style>

But its has no effect (trying in DevTools too)
How i can change icon weight style?
